# How to toggle style dynamically generated elements?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webpage that query a database and dynamically generates elements upon the change in map size. I have a button which upon clicking, enlarges the map and upon a second click, reverts the map back to original size. I want to apply a new style using the `toggleClass` method to the generated elements. The following is the relevant portion of my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
   // resize the map
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // trigger ajax response
   $('.element').toggleClass('new_style'); // this fail to apply new style
  });
 });

 function processData() {
  var div$ = displayResult();
  $('#results').append(div$);
 }

 function displayResult() {
  var R = $('<div class="element">// some content</div>');
  return R;
 }
</script>

<div id='map'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
  $.getJSON(query, processData);
 }
</script>
```

How do I apply the new style to the dynamically generated element? The above doesn't work.

**Note:** I did saw the new_style being applied to the old `<div>`s before they are being replaced with the newly generated ones.

**Further update:** I wrap the statement below with a `setTimeout` function and it worked. Not a need solution though.

```
$('.element').toggleClass('new_style');
```

Comment: Is the first line of code a copy-paste? if so you should quote your class attribute.

Comment: as long as you are not caching the $('.element') query anywhere outside the click function, this should technically work.

Comment: @labroo: sorry, I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: @Ben Huh, class=element should be class="element", check my answer, it's working.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Thanks, I get what jb10210 trying to say now.

Comment: @Ben Huh, welcome and hope you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new element and then "selecting" it using JQuery shoudl work unless code error (see jb comment).

The only thing that won't work is if you bind a method on specific elements and create a new one. The new element won't have the method bind(ed?) unless you use the jquery plugin or function `live`

Comment: The new elements are dynamically generated, i.e. the appended <div>s only come in after the google map event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myDiv=$('<div class="element">some content</div>');    
    $('#results').append(myDiv);

    $('button').click(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // trigger ajax response
        $('.element').toggleClass('new_style'); 
    });
});​
```

A fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xAybx/1/). class=element should be class="element" inside the append in your example.

Comment: Hi, the first line of code is contained within a function which is triggered by the `$.getJSON` method upon a change in map size. I don't think I am able to do it using your method.

Comment: You can register the click handler inside ready event if the button is already inside the DOM and move other codes in your desired function.

Comment: Sorry, can you take a look again. The click handler is indeed already inside the ready event. I didn't show it earlier, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `results`is defined within the div where you have initialized google map. Keeping it outside of the map container should work.

Otherwise you can try the following - just call the JSON request after the map-resizing gets completed.

```
$('button').click(function() {

    // resize the map
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // trigger google map resize

    // var jsonResponse = something goes here

     $('#results').append(jsonResponse);  // append the results
     $('.element').toggleClass('new_style'); // here apply new style
});
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the above again. I have put in additional details. Sorry about that.